# Android error when resizing videoview

Tags: android, resize, android-videoview

I am using a VideoView in a FrameLayout in my main.xml file.
I would like to be able to dynamically resize the VideoView as to minimize/hide it from
the screen. I do not wish to change it's visibility as it will cause problems/crash with another thread which is running my game.

Here is the code

```
 VideoView vv;
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams params;

 vv = (VideoView) findViewById( R.id.gmVideo );
 params = vv.getLayoutParams();
 params.width = gm.StoreX;
 params.height = gm.StoreY;
 vv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The error message i receive is

```
Only the original thread can touch this view
```

Is there a way to modify the VideoView dimensions in code without crashing disrupting the system.
OR Is there only certain places in the Activity or other code in which the modifications can be made without violating access restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way,

```
void temp()
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                vv = (VideoView) findViewById( R.id.gmVideo );  
                params = vv.getLayoutParams();  
                params.width = gm.StoreX;  
                params.height = gm.StoreY;  
                vv.setLayoutParams(params);  
            }
        });
    }
```

also read [when and why to use runOnUIThread() here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ffa222a8a9922ec5)..